# jquery typeWatch with Dynamic input fields added on the fly

Tags: jquery, dynamic, typewatch

How can i get the  Id of the  input field added on the fly? 
My script adds the input fields on click on the button , using

```
var ix = 1;
$(template2(ix++)).appendTo("#dataTable tbody");
var template2 = jQuery.format($("#template2").val());
```

I also add this , line after the insertion of the new fields,  so  it adds the typeWatch to all the .email class fields.

```
$(".email").typeWatch( { highlight:true, callback:function(){alert("changed search text"); },  wait:750  } );
```

now, in the callback function  , I want to get the Id of the input field typeWatch Callback is triggered.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the callback function it looks like this.el contains a DOM object for the element that triggered the callback. So,

```
$(this.el).attr('id')
```

should get you the id you're looking for. This is under version 2.0.0 of the plug-in